# Weblogic 10.3.2 and SHA256withRSA certificate signatures algorim

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x, java-security

The organization I am working for is on weblogic 10.3.2. We are trying to connect to a web service with a certificate signature of SHA256withRSA. If my research is correct, this version of weblogic cannot handle such signatures. (Starting with weblogic 10.3.3, one can enable jsse for such cases)

Do we have any other options other than upgrading weblogic?

Would it be possible to use a different security provider to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using JDK version that supports this.